# $('#id').is(':hidden') returns false even if this element is hidden

Tags: jquery, hidden

I have the following code:

```
<div id="foo" align="right">
    <button type="button" id="bar" name="bar" title="bar" style="display:none;">bar</button>
</div>
```

In IE8 `$('#bar').is(':hidden')` returns false. So I debug the jQuery source code and I found that the problem happens due to the following code:
`set = ret.expr ? Sizzle.filter( ret.expr, ret.set ) : ret.set;`
variable `set` is not assigned correctly.Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $('#bar:hidden') works? I've never seen this pseudo-class, it's jQ specific?

Comment: I cannot replicate this with the latest jQuery (from github source). Can you try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/KH8HN/)? If it still doesn't work you should file a bug.

Comment: @cvsguimaraes - Yes, it's a jQuery pseudo-selector: http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: @cvsguimaraes, yes the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) pseudo-class is a jQ-extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version are you running?

Check this bug:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4512